# JAXB bindings ignore attribute on generating JAXB classes

Tags: jaxb, xjc, jaxb2-basics

I have a schema (.xsd) and on generation using `xjc` would like to ignore some attributes being generated in the `JAXB` classes.

I can remove them manually once generated, but every time when schema changes, it is quite a manual task to remove from the generated class. Is there a way to achieve this using the `JAXB` bindings file or `JAXB2 basics` plugin ?

Comment: You might add `@Transient` using `jaxb2-basics-annotate`  on attribute that you would ignore.

Comment: I would like to **completely skip** the attribute on generation to JAXB classes. `@Transient` would add annotation to the attribute right ? I actually do not want them in the output JAXB at all.

Comment: Yes, it is an annotation on the attribute.